# composeAction in playframework: take one parameter, return the same value, why need it?

Tags: scala, playframework

the function consume an action, return the same action, what's the purpose of it, it has neither side effect nor any transformation. Looks to me it doesn't nothing, like var a=a,how is it useful?

```
protected def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]): Action[A] = action
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, it doesn't do anything, as you say. It's meant as a placeholder to be overridden when composing `Action`s, as described in the [Play 2.2 release highlights](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights22#New-action-composition-and-action-builder-methods) :

> We now provide an ActionBuilder trait for Scala applications that
>   allows more powerful     building of action stacks. For example:

```
object MyAction extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] {
  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
      // Authenticate the action and wrap the request in an authenticated request
      getUserFromRequest(request).map { user =>
          block(new AuthenticatedRequest(user, request))
      } getOrElse Future.successful(Forbidden)
  }

  // Compose the action with a logging action, a CSRF checking action, and an action that only allows HTTPS
  def composeAction[A](action: Action[A]) =
     LoggingAction(CheckCSRF(OnlyHttpsAction(action)))
}
```